# MongoDB $lookup Value Back into Array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, lookup

I have a document with multiple items, that need to lookup further information from another collection to fill out the data.

Main Document:

```
{
  _id: ObjectID("5a30ff41af58f911946b122e"),
  SalesItems: [
    {
      SalesItemID: 1139,
      Quantity: 2,
      Amount: 3.00
    },
    {
      SalesItemID: 2549,
      Quantity: 1,
      Amount: 5.40
    }
  ]
}
```

And then another collection called SalesItem which contains the details for those sales items. Two Documents

```
{
  _id: 1139,
  Name: "Item #1",
  Price: 1.50
}
{
  _id: 2549,
  Name: "Item #2",
  Price: 5.40
}
```

I am trying to do a $lookup in an aggregate to pull the info from the SalesItem Collection into the SalesItems Array of my main Collection. To get a result that looks something like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectID("5a30ff41af58f911946b122e"),
  SalesItems: [
    {
      SalesItemID: 1139,
      Quantity: 2,
      Amount: 3.00,
      SalesItemInfo: {
        _id: 1139,
        Name: "Item #1",
        Price: 1.50
      }
    },
    {
      SalesItemID: 2549,
      Quantity: 1,
      Amount: 5.40,
      SalesItemInfo: {
        _id: 2549,
        Name: "Item #2",
        Price: 5.40
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

I have tried the following but it results in only the SalesItemInfo being present in the SalesItems Object in the result.

```
aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "SalesItem",
            localField: "SalesItems.SalesItemID",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "SalesItems.SalesItemInfo"
        }
    }
])
```

The SalesItem collection has been massively simplified for this example, it is actually around a 990 line JSON Document before being inserted into Mongo. And in the main table it would be replicated around 64 thousand times, hence why I am trying to avoid embedding the info into the main document.

Any help with this would be massively appreciated.

Thanks, Daniel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work it out after a bit more fumbling around with different stages:

```
aggregate([
{
  $unwind: "$SalesItems"  
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "SalesItem",
        localField: "SalesItems.SalesItemID",
        foreignField: "ID",
        as: "SalesItemDetails"
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        SalesItems: {
            $push: {
                SalesItemID: "$SalesItems.SalesItemID",
                SalesItemDetails: "$SalesItemDetails"
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

This results in exactly what I was looking for.