# Mongoose $lookup not response as expect

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, lookup

I want to lookup document from array of object but It not return all of index.

#### Feed document

```
[
  {
    "uuid": "feed-001",
    "comments": [
       { createBy: 'user-001', text: 'Hello' },
       { createBy: 'user-001', text: 'Who there ?' },
       { createBy: 'user-002', text: 'Hi' },
    ],
  },
]
```

#### User Document

```
[
  {
    "uuid": "user-001",
    "name": "Jack",
  },
  {
    "uuid": "user-002",
    "name": "Max",
  },
]
```

#### I tried to query with this

```
FeedModel.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'users',
      localField: 'comments.createBy',
      foreignField: 'uuid',
      as: 'userInfo',
    },
  }
])
```

#### Query Response

But `userInfo` not contain 3 object, IDK why

```
[
  {
    "uuid": "feed-001",
    "comments": [
       { createBy: 'user-001', text: 'Hello' },
       { createBy: 'user-001', text: 'Who there ?' },
       { createBy: 'user-002', text: 'Hi' },
    ],
    "userInfo": [
       {
         "uuid": "user-001",
         "name": "Jack",
       },
       {
         "uuid": "user-002",
         "name": "Max",
       },
    ],
  }
]
```

I need to get userInfo for each comment
Thank you

Comment: you need to $unwind deconstruct comments array and second $lookup and third $group. see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n6clCwsw2mm)

Comment: good, see similar question [MongoDB $lookup Value Back into Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48810826/mongodb-lookup-value-back-into-array)